# how to remove soavee on?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, virus-removal

Thought I had it removed before but now it's back, tried the following:

- Removing the extension from Chrome.
- Disabling the extension and then removing it.
- It's not installed in Windows

The extension keeps adding itself in Chrome and has the following permissions:

- Access your data on all websites
- Access your tabs and browsing activity
- Manage your apps, extensions, and themes

Obviously it's using the last permission to restore itself.

Does anyone know how to kill this one off permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing it by reinstalling chrome, with removing all browsing history.